# invoking command to DC -msexchhidefromaddresslists

Tags: powershell, command, invoke

Im trying to make an AD user attribute: msExchHideFromAddressLists be set true

from powershell documentation and examples i cannot understand why it wont work:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock  {set-adobject -Identity $using:bla -replace @{msexchhidefromaddresslists="$true"}}
```

my error is:
The parameter is incorrect
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CN=shahar test,...adenet,DC=local:ADObject) [Set-ADObject], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:87,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADObject
    + PSComputerName        : DC02

if i replace with other attribue like tits as in this line of code:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock  {set-adobject -Identity $using:bla -replace @{msexchhidefromaddresslists="blabla"}}
```

it does work...
i cant resolve why

Comment: Try `@{msexchhidefromaddresslists=$true}`. No quotes around $true

Comment: Out of curiosity - why execute `Set-ADObject` _on_ the domain controller and not from your own machine?

Comment: this script is a part of a script that does alot of ad changes from a windows10 workstation which use invoke command, i actually didnt know i can set this from the workstation itself and not form invoking to the domain controller

Comment: nah i cant use set-adobject in a normal windows 10 workstation

Comment: Install the RSAT: Active Directory feature package on the workstation, it contains the ActiveDirectory module. The problem with your current approach is that you now _need_ a Domain Admin account to make your changes (because the account need to be able to create a remote logon session on the DC), which in turns exposes the DA credentials on the clients. If, on the other hand, you executed `Set-ADObject` directly on the workstation, the account only needs 1) logon rights on the workstation, and 2) delegated access to the specific AD object(s), Domain Admin is no longer necessary

Comment: I See! thank yo so much for that info. very helpful!